# Can't use SAGA in QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga

I have installed both QGIS 3.22.11-Białowieża and SAGA GIS 7.8.2  in my windows 11 laptop.
Searching in the toolbox of qgis the words "SAGA" it shows this:

[image]

What should i do in order to be available to use it?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to double click on the name of the SAGA-GIS processing algorithm you want to use.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. Yes, it did work, but another problem arises as the algorithms dont seem to run. I tried downloading the plug-in "Processing Saga NextGen Provider" which did seem to make it work.

Comment: To understand why the SAGA-GIS algorithms don't work using the SAGA-GIS provider core plugin, you need to make available the whole processing log.